# Laptop hotspot during sleep mode

Tags: wireless

I turned my laptop into a hotspot what i wish to know if it is possible that my hotspot can be access if my laptop is in sleep mode . Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. Wireless is off in sleep mode.